# ADB2C Rest API not save custom attribute to profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I enabled custom policy in ADB2C and to add more claims I used a rest API to return data for the custom attribute

the response from RESTAPI looks like below :

```
 {
  "version" : "1.0.0",
    "action" : "Continue",
  "extension_<client_id>_empid" : 15,
   "extension_empid" :15,
}
```

and in the claims, I can read this value but actually this value not saving to the user profile so when I fetch the data using graph it's not coming back How I can override this value to user profile
[image]

Comment: Did you use `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail` or something similar to write your custom attribute into AAD?

Comment: yes i added it check the question update I attached my profile

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `extension_empid` claim is defined like this:

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_empid">
  <DisplayName>Employee ID</DisplayName>
  <DataType>long</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

it seems obtaining(parsing from JSON) claim is missing from your REST API, in [Restful technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) `OutputClaims` collection should contain the element:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="getEmployeeInfoAPI">
    <DisplayName>Get Employee info</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          ...
    <OutputClaims>
         ...
         <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_empid" PartnerClaimType="extension_empid" />
    </OutputClaims>

    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

And finally in `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail` technical profile, `PersistedClaims` element should contain the element to persist the data to the directory:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
    ...        
    <PersistedClaims>
       ...
       <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_empid" />
    </PersistedClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: I am using the same thing it's not saving